# htmlAgilityPack HtmlNodeCollection items vs nodes collection

Tags: html-agility-pack

I am using htmlAgilityPack to parse some html values.  I load the document and then do a selectNodes("/html/body//a") and it all works fine.  However, if I do a for each loop like

for each htmlnode in htmlnodecollection.nodes

the htmlnode object has none of the attributes, just the text within the tags.

If I iterate through htmlnodecollection using the item index like
htmlnodecollection(0)
it will give me every possible value of the object.  I would rather do the for each, but looks like I have to do it looking with an integer to get the object by index number.

Is this the way it has to work or am I missing something?